# Why is fromCharCode() returning asian characters?

Tags: javascript

I'm doing a coding challenge that requires turning a string of binary code into text.  when passing in this

> 01000001 01110010 01100101 01101110 00100111 01110100 00100000 01100010 01101111 01101110 01100110 01101001 01110010 01100101 01110011 00100000 01100110 01110101 01101110 00100001 00111111

I get this

> 䉁쥅촶蜏蚠죪촷촶쥎쳉쥅蚠쥎촶蚡눇

instead of Latin characters.

Here's my function

```
function binaryAgent(str) {
  var codedStr = str.split(" ").map(Number),
      decodedStr = "";

  for(var i = 0; i < codedStr.length; i++){
    decodedStr += (String.fromCharCode(codedStr[i]));
  }
  return decodedStr;
}

binaryAgent("01000001 01110010 01100101 01101110 00100111 01110100 00100000 01100010 01101111 01101110 01100110 01101001 01110010 01100101 01110011 00100000 01100110 01110101 01101110 00100001 00111111");
```

can anyone shed light on why this is happening?

Comment: Because when you convert the strings to numbers (`.map(Number)`) you aren't specifying that the strings are in binary.

Comment: `.map(Number)` ... maps to some big numbers - perhaps you meant to parseInt radix 2? `.map(x => parseInt(x, 2))` instead

Comment: You need to use `parseInt` with radix 2 `'01000001 01110010 01100101 01101110 00100111 01110100 00100000 01100010 01101111 01101110 01100110 01101001 01110010 01100101 01110011 00100000 01100110 01110101 01101110 00100001 00111111'.split(' ').map(x => parseInt(x,2)).map(String.fromCharCode).join('')`

Comment: the answer is here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode#Parameters
Try checking the docs of the methods you use, you would see whats the data format that they are expecting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have use this code String.fromCharCode(parseInt(codedStr[i], 2)

```js
function binaryAgent(str) {
  var codedStr = str.split(" ").map(Number),
    decodedStr = "";
  // console.log(codedStr)
  for (var i = 0; i < codedStr.length; i++) {
    // binaryCode.push(String.fromCharCode(parseInt(newBinary[i], 2)));
    decodedStr += (String.fromCharCode(parseInt(codedStr[i], 2)));
  }
  return decodedStr;
}

console.log(binaryAgent("01000001 01110010 01100101 01101110 00100111 01110100 00100000 01100010 01101111 01101110 01100110 01101001 01110010 01100101 01110011 00100000 01100110 01110101 01101110 00100001 00111111"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to convert the binary to decimal to integer value first.

Try to change `(String.fromCharCode(codedStr[i]))`to `(String.fromCharCode(parseInt(codedStr[i], 2)))`

This first converts the binary string to decimal value. The "2" tells that is its numeric system of two (binary).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function binaryAgent(str) {
  var codedStr = str.split(" ").map(Number),
      decodedStr = "";


  for(var i = 0; i < codedStr.length; i++){
    decodedStr += String.fromCharCode(parseInt(codedStr[i], 2));

  }
  return decodedStr;
}

binaryAgent("01000001 01110010 01100101 01101110 00100111 01110100 00100000 01100010 01101111 01101110 01100110 01101001 01110010 01100101 01110011 00100000 01100110 01110101 01101110 00100001 00111111");
```